# Is there a way to get personalized email preview (thumbnails) in salesforce per contact?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

A client has a requirement coming from Silverpop. They want to be able to see dynamic content per Contact when looking at an email preview. Currently in the Salesforce Connector, users are only able to see a generic preview which doesn't even display default dynamic content. This makes the preview virtually unusable for end users who wish to see which email has been sent to the contact or lead.

Is there a way to get this kind of preview or some known ways of deriving this feature programmatically?

Comment: Is this referring to after the fact of the email being sent, or before? If it's before an email is sent you can use this functionality: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/dynamic_send_preview/

If you need a record of the dynamic content after an email, it's not as easy. One of the ways I've used is to use AMPscript to deposit the entire HTML of the email into a Data Extension field. A good guide can be found here: http://webep.fr/feed-a-send-log-send-history-data-extension-automatically/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this in Marketing Cloud via Send Preview, selecting your preview list or Data Extension, selecting the first subscriber and then scrolling through them using the arrows next to the subscriber's email address in the top bar.  I'm not sure that gives you the answer you want in terms of visibility from Salesforce, but it's a possibility if your client is willing to go into Marketing Cloud itself.